# Inconsistent geolocation query results in SQL

Tags: sql, join, geolocation, between

I wrote a simple web application that lets you mark flea market stands on a google map.
Each stand is stored in a **sqlite3** database with its geolocation and other information.
This is the CREATE statement for the stands table:

```
CREATE TABLE stands (
id INTEGER PRIMARY_KEY,
name TEXT,
address TEXT,
u REAL,
v REAL,
);
```

u and v are respectively Latitude and Longitude.
Additionally I have a cities table that stores the name and geographic bounds of each city which host a stand. This is used to let users quickly navigate between cities.

```
CREATE TABLE cities
(name TEXT PRIMARY_KEY,
u_min REAL,
u_max REAL,
v_min REAL,
v_max REAL);
```

When a new stand is added, a new row is added to the cities table or if the stand is in a known city, only the bounds of the city are updated if needed.

Here are some sample stands:

```
592077673|Kierrätystori Rovaniemellä|Urheilukatu 1, 96100 Rovaniemi, Suomi|66.4978306921681|25.7220569153442
1321495145|Kruununhaka|Liisankatu, 00170 Helsinki, Suomi|60.1742596|24.9555782    
571688977|Viikki asukastalo LAVAn edusta|Biologinkatu 5, 00790 Helsinki, Suomi|60.2342312|25.04058
563089951|Hämeentie 156|Hämeentie 156, 00560 Helsinki, Suomi|60.2130467082539|24.9785856067459    
518892420|Joensuu - Ilosaari|Siltakatu 1, 80100 Joensuu, Finland|62.5990455742272|29.7706540507875
```

and cities:

```
    Rovaniemi|66.4978306921681|66.4978306921681|25.7220569153442|25.7220569153442
Helsinki|60.1577049447137|60.2556221042622|24.9216988767212|25.0662129772156
Järvenpää|60.4513724|60.4513724|25.0819323000001|25.0819323000001
Joensuu|62.5990455742272|62.5990653244875|29.7706540507874|29.7706540507875
Vantaa|60.2731724937748|60.2731724937748|24.9571491285278|24.9571491285278
```

The issue I'm having is retrieving the the number of stands per cities.
So far I've been using the following query:

```
SELECT cities.name AS city,
  cities.u_min,
  cities.u_max,
  cities.v_min,
  cities.v_max,
  count(stands.id) AS count
FROM cities
LEFT OUTER JOIN stands
  ON ((stands.u BETWEEN cities.u_min AND cities.u_max)
    AND(stands.v BETWEEN cities.v_min AND cities.v_max))
GROUP BY cities.name;
```

This returns:

```
Helsinki|60.1577049447137|60.2556221042622|24.9216988767212|25.0662129772156|9
**Joensuu|62.5990455742272|62.5990653244875|29.7706540507874|29.7706540507875|0**
Järvenpää|60.4513724|60.4513724|25.0819323000001|25.0819323000001|1
Rovaniemi|66.4978306921681|66.4978306921681|25.7220569153442|25.7220569153442|1
Vantaa|60.2731724937748|60.2731724937748|24.9571491285278|24.9571491285278|1
```

Which is not correct as the city named Joensuu does have 1 stand in its boundaries:

```
518892420|Joensuu - Ilosaari|Siltakatu 1, 80100 Joensuu, Finland|62.5990455742272|29.7706540507875
```

But the following query returns the expected stand:

```
SELECT * FROM stands where u between 62.5990455742272 and 62.5990653244875 and v between 29.7706540507874 and 29.7706540507875;
```

I really can't understand what is going wrong here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

By the way, I imported this database to Mysql and the same thing happens so I doubt this is a sqlite3 bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with floating point precision error. One of the ways to deal with such problems is to introduce a small number and add it to your boundaries to make them a little wider - that eliminates precision errors.

One approach is to widen boundaries in every query directly:

```
SET @e = 0.0000000000001;

SELECT cities.name AS city,
  cities.u_min,
  cities.u_max,
  cities.v_min,
  cities.v_max,
  count(stands.id) AS count
FROM cities
LEFT OUTER JOIN stands
  ON ((stands.u BETWEEN cities.u_min - @e AND cities.u_max + @e)
    AND(stands.v BETWEEN cities.v_min - @e AND cities.v_max + @e))
GROUP BY cities.name;
```

Another approach is to store the widened boundaries in the cities table:

```
SET @e = 0.0000000000001;

UPDATE cities
SET cities.u_min = cities.u_min - @e,
  cities.u_max = cities.u_max + @e,
  cities.v_min = cities.v_min - @e,
  cities.v_max = cities.v_max + @e;
```

P.S. I am not sure if the variable syntax works in SQLite, but if doesn't, just substitute all `@e` with `0.0000000000001`.

Comment: No, the SET syntax is not supported by sqlite. I manually patched the database and modified the PHP script that handles database transactions to widened the boundaries on creation and update.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you use `LEFT JOIN`, so it includes all cities, regardless of whether there is a match in the `stands` table. Notice how `COUNT` returns `0` for that row.

Just use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`. That will tell MySQL to only return rows for which the condition in `ON` is met.

**UPD**: I misunderstood the question, so this answer is wrong. I'll post another answer.

Comment: Thank you but the INNER JOIN does not solve the problem. The COUNT for the Joensuu row should return 1 not 0 because there is a stand in the bounds of the city (Lat : 62.5990455742272 - 62.5990653244875, Long : 29.7706540507874 - 29.7706540507875) : **518892420|Joensuu - Ilosaari|Siltakatu 1, 80100 Joensuu, Finland|62.5990455742272|29.7706540507875**\n The problem is somewhere in the ON condition, for some reason the stand does not get counted.